# AWS Elasticsearch frequently getting into yellow state

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

- I have AWS Elasticsearch running with 3 Master nodes(C4.large) and 10
  data nodes(C5.large). Recently I am experiencing  frequently that my
  domain gets into yellow state for some time around 30 mins and then i
  do nothing it changes to green.
- when i used the query `GET /_cluster/allocation/explain?pretty` this is what i see

```
{
  "index" : "lgst-",
  "shard" : 4,
  "primary" : false,
  "current_state" : "unassigned",
  "unassigned_info" : {
    "reason" : "NODE_LEFT",
    "at" : "2021-01-06T13:15:38.721Z",
    "details" : "node_left [**************]",
    "last_allocation_status" : "no_attempt"
  },
  "can_allocate" : "yes",
  "allocate_explanation" : "can allocate the shard",
  "target_node" : {
    "id" : "****************",
    "name" : "********************"
  },
```

- I couldn't understand what does it mean and how do i over come it. Any help please would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using spot instances in your cluster and cause for this is that nodes in your AWS is not stable as shown clearly in the `unassigned_info`

```
"unassigned_info" : {
    "reason" : "NODE_LEFT",
    "at" : "2021-01-06T13:15:38.721Z",
    "details" : "node_left [**************]",
    "last_allocation_status" : "no_attempt"
  },
```

I would suggest chaning the instance types if you are using [ec2 spot instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-instances.html) and check why nodes are getting disconnected in your cluster with AWS support.

Comment: I can't find the info whether it is an Spot or Ondemand

Comment: @RahulRavichandran people who created this would know it or you can find a lot of info on how to identify it

Comment: Yes I changed the instance type to c4.large and it is working fine from then on .. but not sure of the root cause

Comment: @RahulRavichandran, what was the instance type earlier, maybe your instances were running out of memory sporadically??